# Why is the following set not a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have the following set and I want to know whether it's a vector space or not:

> $W = \{(x, y, z) ∈ \Bbb R^3 : (x + y)(2y − z) = 0\}$

Now, I understand that if I have a set W and it's a vector space then $0\in W$ and it should have vector addition and scalar multiplication for some $w_1, w_2 \in W$.

But how to I use the definition to check if the vector space is not linear in that case?

I know that $0\in W$. What about the other checks? How is it done?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean to ask whether it is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$? In that case, just try a few examples to see what goes wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not closed under addition. For example, $(0,0,z)$, where $z$ is an arbitrary number, is in $W$.

Now find another vector in $W$, for example $(1,1,2)$. Add these two together. You get $(1,1,z+2)$, again, where $z$ is arbitrary. This is clearly not in $W$, except for $z=0$.

Comment: $(0,0,z) + (1,1,2) = (1, 1, 2+z)$, but it is still true, since $(1+1)(2-(2+z)) = -2z=0$ satisfies only $z=0$, but any other $z$ does not - however it still lies in the set.

Comment: @quapka: It is not in the set except for your example. I edited.

Comment: I meant, that $(0,0,z) \in W, \forall z \in \mathbb{R}$. My comment might confuse someone, but your answer is now correct. Also your choice of $(1,1,2)$ is not that arbitrary, but that is clear, I guess.

Comment: @quapka: I'll just add a note then. The choice of $(1,1,2)$ can be made using any nonzero $x,y$ values, with $z=2y$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$In case some theory helps clarify your strategy: Your set $W$ is the union of two planes through the origin:
$$
W_{1} = \{(x, y, z) \in \Reals^{3} : x + y = 0\},\qquad
W_{2} = \{(x, y, z) \in \Reals^{3} : 2y - z = 0\},
$$
since $(x + y)(2y - z) = 0$ if and only if $x + y = 0$ or $2y - z = 0$.

In an arbitrary vector space, a union of subspaces is non-empty and closed under scalar multiplication. In this example, you should therefore focus immediately on closure under addition.

A union of two subspaces, neither contained in the other, is *never* closed under addition: If $w_{1} \in W_{1} \setminus W_{2}$ and $w_{2} \in W_{2} \setminus W_{1}$, then $w_{1} + w_{2} \not\in W_{1} \cup W_{2}$. This is an easy, worthwhile exercise. (Hint: Assume contrapositively that $w_{1}$ and $w_{1} + w_{2}$ are elements of $W$. What can you say about $w_{2}$?)

To check that your $W$ is not closed under addition, just pick a vector $w_{1}$ in $W_{1}$ that is *not* an element of $W_{2}$, and similarly pick $w_{2}$ in $W_{2}$ not not in $W_{1}$, and verify $w_{1} + w_{2} \not\in W$.